# What package does debugger command 'x' belong to?

Tags: perl

I'm using perl's debugger and want to execute the debugger's x function, how do I execute command 'x' after each prompt?

I know that the command `> print $var;` will cause the print function to be executed after every prompt, but how do I do `> x $var`?

I'm thinking if I import x from it's package, this should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no subroutine `x` in the debugger. The `x` command at the debugger prompt eventually calls the function `DB::dumpit` which expects a filehandle as its first argument. So you could say

```
> DB::dumpit( $DB::OUT, $var )
```

Before I looked all of that up (in the source of [`perl5db.pl`](https://metacpan.org/source/RJBS/perl-5.18.1/lib/perl5db.pl)), if I had the same problem as you, I probably would have just said

```
use Data::Dumper
> print Dumper($var)
```